# Launch a Jar in Debian 7.9

Tags: java, bash, debian, sh, beagleboneblack

i did a runnable jar and it goes good in my Debian, i want to autolanch it when my beaglebone board starts and kill it when it goes in shutdown. I tried with this file.sh inside the folder /etc/init.d

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myscript.sh
# Required-Start:    $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: myscript.sh
### END INIT INFO
# MyApp
#
# description: It lanch the Jar file 

case $1 in
    start)
        /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myapp-start.sh
    ;;
    stop)
        /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myapp-stop.sh
    ;;
    restart)
        /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myapp-stop.sh
        /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myapp-start.sh
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

I created also myapp-start.sh and stop in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/java -jar myjar.jar
```

and for the stop:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Grabs and kill a process 

pid=`ps aux | grep myapp | awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 $pid
```

when i launch the update-rc.d myscript.sh defaults i received it:
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing

What else i can do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of problems:

1. You should NOT indent the `#!/bin/bash` line in any of your scripts.  It will only work if the `#!` characters are the first two character of the file, etcetera.  (The OS kernel decodes this line in a script file, and is is very picky.)

   The file also needs to have the appropriate execute bit set in the file's permissions; e.g. "ls -l myapp-start.s" needs to show an "x" for user, group or other.
2. If you have the `#!` line correct, then you can run the script like this:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/myapp-start.sh
   ```
3. This is almost certainly incorrect:

   ```
    /home/java -jar myjar.jar
   ```

   Two problems:

   - Unless you've done something bizarre, `/home/java` is not the correct pathname for the `java` command.
   - You have specified the JAR filename using a relative path.  It is unclear what the current directory will be if / when `java` is run, but it is unlikely that the `myjar.jar` file will be in the current directory.

---

A useful trick for debugging shell scripts like this is to add `set -x` or `set -v` to the script to see what it is doing.  Please refer to `man bash` for details on what that does.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the 1) is right on the left, the 2) it is unable to access to my jar file (is in one other directory), 3) i tried with java -jar myjar.jar too,  some others advices?

Comment: Even if i put my jar inisde that directory (in this way i solve temporarily my path problem), i receive the same answer from the update-rc.d . Some other solutions to make it operational?

Comment: *"some others advices?"* - See my last paragraph.  Then cut and paste actual command line that the script is attempting to execute.  (Hint: it is very difficult to advise someone who says "I tried that and it didn't work" when the "that" is not clearly, completely and precisely stated.)

Comment: Hint 2: this stuff is not rocket science ... but you take the approach of randomly trying various things without understanding why they do / do not work, then it is rather like voodoo / black magic.

Comment: Hint 3: one thing you may not have considered is that "unable to access file" problems can be due to directory or file permissions problems.  Or sandboxing ... if you are running on a server with SE-Linux in "enforcing" mode.

Comment: At first sorry for my not clear answer, i wanted establish a peaceful dialogue with all people that like reply to this type of questions. I have tried with chmod u+x already before to launch update command. I will try as you said with  the debugging  adding set -x and set -v, if i found a solution after that I have studied and tried in this way, i will put here a clear answer.